# npm command not working,showing the error "Cannot find module 'strip-ansi''

Tags: npm, gruntjs, node-modules

Recently i come across an issue .......when ever i try to start my project with command like .....`npm start` ,it will display the issue and what ever the command i do related to npm it will show the error.

Even when i try to check my npm version,i get the error.

What i guess is there is something installed globally that because of  which the error occurs.

I completely had no idea about this,can someone help me...Thanks. 
issue:

```
Cannot find module 'strip-ansi'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and here is how I solved it:

because you're trying to upgrade sails I think this might be a problem with your currently installed packages. Have you tried removing your node_modules folder, (cleaning the npm cache) and re-installing your node packages?

```
cd /path/to/your/sails/folder
rm -r node_modules
npm cache clean
npm install
```

Source: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2744